# Is it possible to load and execute C# snippets using DLR?

Tags: c#, dynamic-language-runtime, embedded-language

The majority of material I have found regarding DLR is related to IronPython.  Can you parse and execute C# using DLR?  If so is there over head that would prevent you from attempting this on a web server with about 30 users?

More specifically I would like to script the configuration of my workflow objects when a user first initiates a workflow.  Depending on conditions that change through out the year workflows may start at different steps, hence running configuration scripts seems like a good way to handle the variation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although Marc offered an alternative for me, I read this related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297624/vbx-language-hosting-via-dlr) and C# and VB are not supported as of yet.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you're really talking about the C# "compiler as a service" (at the end of [this video](http://channel9.msdn.com/pdc2008/TL16/)), which will hopefully be in the 5.0 timescale for .NET (although Mono [has it now](http://www.go-mono.com/docs/index.aspx?link=N:Mono.CSharp)). For now, [CSharpCodeProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx) is the best we have (which works largely like "csc").

Comment: Thanks - was reading your blog today.  Good stuff.  Basically I debating whether I go the CSScript.net route or pursue the CSharpCodeProvider way.

Comment: Marc, can you recommend some good samples beyond the MSDN link?  Thanks again.

Comment: Which - compiler as a service? Kinda hard, since it doesn't exist and won't for another year or so (at a guess). Or did I misunderstand the question...?

Comment: I don't know of any *specific* ones - but it isn't hard an IMO the MSDN example shows a lot of it. The main trick is remembering to includ C# 3.0: var compiler = new CSharpCodeProvider(new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "CompilerVersion", "v3.5" } });

Answer (score 0):

You may find this relevant...though it doesn't run on the DLR itself.

[Mono Compiler as a Service (MCS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407318/mono-compiler-as-a-service-mcs)

It has the advantage of running snippets and not loading a new assembly on every compile like CodeDom does.