# Dynamic LINQ API with .NET Framework 4

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4

Is Dynamic LINQ API (released with the CSharpSamples), still the way to go, or is there a different / alternative approach with .NET 4 (and [EF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET_Entity_Framework) 4)?

Answer (score 1):

See my post here please for some generic options:
[Parsing a string C# LINQ expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3782538/parsing-a-string-c-linq-expression).

Also EF 4 does have some built in string query parsing functionality added in...but it's completely specific to EF itself. See here for example:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338811.aspx