# How to use an ExpressionTree to create a predicate that utilizes a Regex

Tags: c#, regex, expression, predicate

I am manually building a predicate for filtering data in a CollectionView and I want to add the ability to filter a particular field via a user supplied Regex. Writing the predicate directly would give something like:

```
string userRegex = "abc.+";
Predicate<object> myPredicate = p => Regex.IsMatch(((MyType).p).MyField, userRegex);
```

So I could pass the pattern in to my Predicate Factory and do something like this (off the top of my head and not tried - not sure about the Call syntax):

```
string userRegex = "abc.+";
var paramObject = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "p");
var paramMyType = Expression.TypeAs(paramObject, typeof(MyType));
var propMyField = Expression.Property(paramMyType, "MyField");
var constRegex = Expression.Constant(userRegex);

var methodInfo = typeof(Regex).GetMethod("IsMatch", new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(string) } );
var params = new Expression[] { propMyField, constRegex }

var lamdaBody = Expression.Call(methodInfo, params);
var lamda = Expression.Lambda<Func<object, bool>>(lamdaBody, paramObject);
var myPredicate = new Predicate<object>(lamda.Compile());
```

But my gut feeling says that this will create an expression that will rebuild the Regex from the pattern on every call to the predicate.  Is this gut feeling correct?

If my gut feeling is correct then is it possible to pre-build the Regex before creating the Expression that consumes it?  And if so, how?

Or if I am totally off the beam, who should this be done?

(Also is my Call syntax correct??)

---

**Edit**

Just to clear up some things.

1. The predicate I am building is destined for a `CollectionView.Filter`, so the signature has to be `Predicate<object>`
2. Even though I am only showing a Regex in my example, the predicate I am actually building (dynamically) has many other clauses.  The rest have been left out for clarity.
3. The predicate itself is only built after the user clicks around some options and then presses a button.  This is done infrequently even when compared to other UI activities.
4. When the predicate is applied, it will be applied to 10,000 to 20,000 (or more) objects in the collection backing the CollectionView
5. There are very few other Regex's on my program, so I think Filip's observation about caching the last 15 patterns means that my gut feeling is probably wrong.
6. But I still want to do something like Filip's answer and somehow capture a compiled version of the Regex in the Expression Tree that I am building.

Comment: `user supplied Regex` - Not a bullet proof way at all. What are you going to do wrap it in exception handling?

Comment: @sln Yes I have left out various items for the sake of clarity.  Anyway in my actual application the UI layer (actually the view model bound to the control that handles all the user selections for the filter parameters) has already validated the string as a Regex before the data gets anywhere near my predicate factory.

Comment: `validated the string as a Regex` as far as I know, the only way to validate a Dot-Net regex is to compile it, unless you know how to parse it before .Net does.

Comment: I usually just create a helper method with the regex inside the helper.  In this case the helper can return a boolean.

Comment: @jdweng I could do that except that I have decoupled everything and the filter view model, predicate factory and collection view model are all in different objects.  So i need to treat the predicate a piece of data to be passed around.  To do it how you do it would ruin that decoupling.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use a Predicate and not a Func<string,string,bool>? Then you won't need to recompile the whole tree and can just pass it as an argument to the method?

Comment: @FilipCordas I'm plugging this into a `CollectionView` and the signature of the Filter for that type is `Predicate<object>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, it is not clear why do you use  Expression Tree / dynamic code generation at all. Is performance really that critical that you can't afford creating your compound `Predicate` joining other (smaller) `Predicate`s?

Secondly, I'm not sure I understand where you see issues with changing your code to use compiled `RegEx`. Is following code what you wanted:

```
    static Predicate<object> CreateRegExPredicateSmart(string pattern)
    {
        var regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled);
        var paramObject = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "p");
        var paramMyType = Expression.TypeAs(paramObject, typeof(MyType));
        var propMyField = Expression.Property(paramMyType, "MyField");
        var constRegex = Expression.Constant(regex);

        var methodInfo = typeof(Regex).GetMethod("IsMatch", new Type[] { typeof(string) });
        var paramsEx = new Expression[] { propMyField };

        var lamdaBody = Expression.Call(constRegex, methodInfo, paramsEx);
        Expression<Func<object, bool>> lamdaSmart = Expression.Lambda<Func<object, bool>>(lamdaBody, paramObject);

        return new Predicate<object>(lamdaSmart.Compile());
    }
```

**Note** that what RegexOptions.Compiled [actually does](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs(v=vs.110).aspx#Compiled) might be not exactly what you expected but it seems to make sense in your context.

Comment: 1) I am building my predicate from dynamic code as I have about 20 totally different, independent potential clauses (chosen at run time by the user depending on what they want)  that I need to test against 20,000+ objects. 2) I was not sure how to actually capture the compiled Regex in the predicate as I am new this particular area of C#.  Your answer is the first example I have seen that makes sense to me. I always thought of `Expression.Constant` being a fixed value, and not an object you could issue a function call against.

Comment: I just implemented your code and it worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This will only compile once the property portion of the expression. Hope this will help you a bit.

```
public static class PropertyGetter<T>
    {
        private static Dictionary<string, Func<T, string>> cache = new Dictionary<string, Func<T, string>>();

        public static Func<T, string> Get(string propertyName)
        {
            if (!cache.ContainsKey(propertyName))
            {
                var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
                Expression<Func<T, string>> exp = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, string>>(Expression.Property(param, propertyName),param);
                cache[propertyName] = exp.Compile();
            }
            return cache[propertyName];
        }

        public static Predicate<object> GetPredicate(string propertyName, string pattern)
        {
            Func<T, string> getter = Get(propertyName);
            Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled);

            return (obj) => regex.IsMatch(getter((T)obj));            }
    }
```

As long as you have the reference to the Predicate it will use the came regex. But the best way to check this is just to run it on some test data and see what you will get. The method [Regex.IsMatch(String, String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg578045(v=vs.110).aspx) by default caches the last 15 most recently used static regular expression patterns. So if you don't go over the limit the expression implementation should not recompile the whole thing. But the best way is to just test as much as you can and see what happens.

Comment: I'm going to look at this tomorrow or Monday.   I haven't fully worked through your code yet (and my Predicate factory also dynamically builds in another 18-20 clauses - but the predicate is only rebuilt infrequently ) but I think the key thing is that caching of the last 15 Regex patterns.  I think that tells me that my gut feeling was wrong.  So in summary the pattern is fairly stable so it probably will be cached, but the predicate is built infrequently so I am not sure your caching is needed.  However the predicate is going to be applied to 10,000 to 20,000 items.