# How to create regex for mathing linq statement NOT contains where clause?

Tags: c#, regex, linq

I have a very large codebase in which in want to find all linq statements that not contain the where cause.

So, lets say I have a linq statement like this:

```
from t in dc.tablename where t.somefield="somevalue" select t
```

This statement should NOT be included into the search result, but, if the statement looks like this:

```
from t in dc.tablename select t
```

this should be included into the search result.

So far I've only managed to create a regex for matching linq statements that contain the WHERE:

```
from(.|\n){1,}(where)(.|\n){1,}select
```

But when I try this:

```
from(.|\n){1,}^(where)(.|\n){1,}select
```

it does not work.

Comment: What kind of regex would that be? The kind used by the Visual Studio search box?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3782538/parsing-a-string-c-sharp-linq-expression

Comment: Marnix: yeah, I wanna use it in the VS search box.

Comment: roland: I think this question is nothing to do with mine..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could maybe try out this regex:

```
from(?:(?!where|select)[\s\S])+select
```

`(?:(?!where|select)[\s\S])+` will match any characters (including newlines) except `where` and `select` so that you don't have to worry about greediness either.

Comment: thanks, it seems to be working, although it gives fake results also, but at least I've found the LINQs.

Comment: @user1307533 Okay. Could you perhaps give an example of fake results? If it helps you getting only the relevant lines :)

Comment: For example:
/// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.

This is also a result, but I don't understand why.. maybe the Visual Studio's regex search is f*cked up somehow :)

Comment: @user1307533 Nah, it's matching all right. Do all the LINQs you need begin on a new line with `select`? If so, you could simply add `^[ \t]*` at the beginning of the regex. This will make sure to match only lines that begin with `from` (with optional indentation).